# Solved - Adding Mass Delete Action to the Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, custom, backend, massaction

I have created a custom module and need to add checkboxes to the grid and be able to delete multiple values with a mass action.
Tried to use number of different articles but nothing worked. 
Can anyone help me to do this or maybe you know a good working article about this?

Here is the code in controller file:

```
    public function massDeleteAction() {
       $requestIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
       if(!is_array($requestIds)) {
       Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Please select reqeust(s)'));
       } else {
       try {
        foreach ($requestIds as $requestId) {
            $RequestData = Mage::getModel('cpstest_productcomment/cps_collection')->load($requestId);                    
            $RequestData->delete();                    
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
            Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__(
                'Total of %d record(s) were successfully deleted', count($requestIds)
            )
        );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
```

Comment: can you get your solution??

Comment: Please add code for your grid file and controller file

Comment: @Jaimin Sutariya thank you guys for responding, I added the codes.

Comment: Are you sure you are using correct Model here `Mage::getModel('cpstest_productcomment/cps_collection')` IT seems like the model is not found.

Comment: @Jaimin Sutariya you are right, I just changed the model name and it worked :)))) Thank you all guys, you're amazing!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also try this code.
Put below code into your `grid.php`

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $this->setMassactionIdField('id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('your_field');

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
         'label'    => Mage::helper('your_helper')->__('Delete'),
         'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
         'confirm'  => Mage::helper('your_helper')->__('Are you sure?')
    ));

    return $this;
}
```

Put below code into your `admin controller`

```
public function massDeleteAction() {
    $requestIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('your_field');
    if(!is_array($requestIds)) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Please select reqeust(s)'));
    } else {
        try {
            foreach ($requestIds as $requestId) {
                $RequestData = Mage::getModel('your_model')->load($requestId);                    
                $RequestData->delete();                    
            }
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
                Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__(
                    'Total of %d record(s) were successfully deleted', count($requestIds)
                )
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks so much for your answer. I used these codes and got an error. Please take a look at the print screen I'm adding now.

Comment: I made  a mistake in the model name, just made a correction and it worked :)))) Thanks so much. By the way, I also wanted to say that your solution is the best, I tried so many different codes ,they were more complicated and didn't work..

Comment: It's my pleasure @bestwebdevs

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a function in your grid file in which you have written code for adding grid columns. I am providing you an example for mass action of catalog grid on admin panel. Please check below code:

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('product');

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Delete'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
         'confirm' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Are you sure?')
    ));

    $statuses = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getOptionArray();

    array_unshift($statuses, array('label'=>'', 'value'=>''));
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('status', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Change status'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massStatus', array('_current'=>true)),
         'additional' => array(
                'visibility' => array(
                     'name' => 'status',
                     'type' => 'select',
                     'class' => 'required-entry',
                     'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Status'),
                     'values' => $statuses
                 )
         )
    ));

    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('catalog/update_attributes')){
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('attributes', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Update Attributes'),
            'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/catalog_product_action_attribute/edit', array('_current'=>true))
        ));
    }

    Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_catalog_product_grid_prepare_massaction', array('block' => $this));
    return $this;
}
```